# Calculate the probability that worm move along the edges

Tags: probability, combinations

Rectangular box $ABCD.A'B'C'D'$. At vertex $A$ there is a worm. It moves along the edges of the box and goes to a vertex adjacent to the vertex it is standing. Calculate the probability that after nine moves it stands at vertex $C'$.

```
example : A-B-C-B-A-D-A-B-C-C’
```

I think I need  a recursive formula, but I do not know how to formulate it.

Comment: It would help to be a little bit clearer about the geometry...until seeing Christian's answer I didn't understand that this is a 3D problem. (Just using "cube" or "prism" would've been enough to fix that.)

Comment: Time to start writing better questions, J.doe, and showing some effort.  This is not a do-my-work-for-me-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote by $p_n$ the probability that after $n$ moves the worm is at one of the *poles* $A$ or $C'$. Then
$$p_0=1,\qquad p_{n+1}={1\over3}(1-p_n)\qquad(n\geq0)\ .\tag{1}$$
*Proof.* You can get to a pole from any one of the six non-poles.  The probability that after $n$ moves the worm is at a non-pole is $1-p_n$, and with probability ${1\over3}$ he then decides to move to a  pole. (I'm assuming that the worm does not remember where he came from.)

Subtracting ${1\over4}$ on both sides of $(1)$ we obtain
$$p_{n+1}-{1\over4}=-{1\over3}\left(p_n-{1\over4}\right)\ .$$
This implies
$$p_n={1\over4}+\left(-{1\over3}\right)^n\cdot{3\over4}\qquad(n\geq0)\ ,$$
and in particular $$p_9={1640\over6561}\ .$$ Now after $9$ moves the worm cannot be at $A$, since the cube graph is bipartite. Therefore with probability $p_9$  it is at $C'$ after $9$ moves.

Comment: Oh .i understand but so that  count number  the way of the following 9 steps to C’ is difficul

Comment: Can you explain detail more than why Denote by $p_n$ the probability that after $n$ moves the worm is on one of $A$ or $C'$. Then
$$p_0=1,\qquad p_{n+1}={1\over3}(1-p_n)\qquad(n\geq0)\ ,\tag{1}$$

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: You wanted a recursive formula; you got one. It is also possible to set up an $8\times 8$ matrix $A$ and then compute $A^9[1,0,\ldots,0]'$.

Comment: Can you explain detail more than ?

Comment: I want a way in which the students high school or secondary can understand it